# Install python3 and pip3 on a offline linux server

Tags: python, linux, pip

I have installed Python on an offline server but I cannot install pip

this is what I have done :

1 ) Download the archive file `pip-21.3.1.tar.gz` and put it on my offline Linux server. extract the archive file.

2 ) `cd pip-21.3.1`

3 ) Run `python3 setup.py install`

and this is the error that I get :

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'
```

Comment: Which exactly operating system are you using?

Comment: "Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"

Answer (score 0):

That's because you need to install `setuptools` - which is the separate module.

Alternative (and prefered) solution would be to install `pip3` using `rpm` packages (here's seems to be instruction for that:
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/6996

Answer (score 0):

You might try using [`ensurepip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html) if you have `python3.4` or newer, as it

> ...*does not* access the internet. All of the components needed to
> bootstrap `pip` are included as internal parts of the package.

in your case

```
python3 -m ensurepip
```

should suffice

Comment: not working  I a long message starting with `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 520, in _get_decompress_func
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zlib'` and finish with `r\'pip\']\nrunpy.run_module("pip", run_name="__main__", alter_sys=True)\n']' returned non-zero exit status 1.`

Comment: @name this is surprising for me, as [`zlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html) is part of standard library. I have not experience with *Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server* so I am unable to say why that happend or how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You already got an answer on how to solve the problem. The reason why you need to install `setuptools` is that pip's `setup.py` starts with:

```
import os
import sys

from setuptools import find_packages, setup
```

As you can see the last line tries to import from setuptools that is not from the standard library.

If the Python you're using is the one that has been installed with `rpm`, go and use `rpm` as already suggested. If the Python has been custom installed,  that command may not solve yout problem: suppose you installed Python 3.9 and system Python is 3.7, the site-package directory would be different.

Answer (score 0):

I face this problem either. I reckon up some methods .

1.Install  python >=v3.7 with fulll components (pip absolutely).
But the key is how to ensure it has pip.

2.If you want to install setuptools for installing pip, you willl discover Prerequisite of installing  setuptools is dataclasses. ╮(╯▽╰)╭