# How do I install Python 3 with all its tools on a offline Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server?

Tags: python, linux

How do I install Python 3 with all its tools on a offline Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server ?

I have tried these: Download the archive file, put it on my offline linux server, and then extract the archive file. And install python, but the tools weren't installed.

Some people suggest me to use rpm but I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: What tools are you talking about?

Comment: I want to install pip3 , for this 1 ) I download the archive file `pip-21.3.1.tar.gz` and put it on my offline linux server. extract the archive file.

2 ) `cd pip-21.3.`

3 ) Run`python3 setup.py install`

Comment: but I get this message : `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'`

Comment: for install pip3 Some people tell me to use `python3 -m ensurepip` but for use this command I have to install python with rpm

Comment: As pointed out in [an answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70365656/1126841), you need to install `setuptools` before you can install `pip` in this way.